# Oracle SQL Developer - expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I'm following this [guide](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936) to avoid mutation errors since I used to query the table that fired the trigger and that obviously doesn't work. So I created this package as the guide clearly says.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE NOVOANOLECTIVO
AS

  TYPE ANOARRAY IS TABLE OF ROWID INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  NOVOSTUPLOS ANOARRAY;
  VAZIO ANOARRAY;

END;
```

And the following trigger doesn't compile because it says "expression is of wrong type". But I'm just following the guide so what seems to be the problem ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_AFTERANO 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ANOLECTIVO
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

POSICAO INTEGER;

BEGIN
--APANHAR O CODIGO DOS NOVOS TUPLOS
  POSICAO := NOVOANOLECTIVO.NOVOSTUPLOS.COUNT + 1;

   NOVOANOLECTIVO.NOVOSTUPLOS(POSICAO) := :NEW.CODIGO;

END;
```

Comment: For start `NOVOSTUPLOS` is not initialized in anywhere.

Comment: It's that the cause of the error?

Comment: I can't say because you didn't said where is the line on your code that the error is happening. But it could

Comment: `NOVOANOLECTIVO.NOVOSTUPLOS(POSICAO) := :NEW.CODIGO;`. This is the line.

Comment: So the error is because you are putting the `:new.codigo` on NOVOSTUPLOS(POSICAO) which is a table of ROWID it means that :new.codigo has to be the same type of ROWID (whatever is this, I know it just in a query.) But it isn't

Comment: Yeah I was following blindly the guide. I just replaced this line `TYPE ANOARRAY IS TABLE OF ROWID INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;` with this `TYPE ANOARRAY IS TABLE OF AnoLectivo.codigo%type INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`. Thanks mate.

Comment: Glad that I could help. I will put it as an answer, so you can accept it ok?!

Comment: Of course, since you helped me that's the least I can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comments that the error is on this line `NOVOANOLECTIVO.NOVOSTUPLOS(POSICAO) := :NEW.CODIGO;` it means that the error is because you are putting the `:new.codigo` on `NOVOSTUPLOS(POSICAO)` which is a table of `ROWID` type and  `:new.codigo` should be the same type of `ROWID` (whatever is this, I know it just in a query.) But it isn't.